# Segmentation fault core dumped : Function that returns the next prime number

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, primes, coredump

I get segmentation fault core dumped. My function is supposed to return the prime number following the one put in parameters, or to return the number if it is a prime.

When I compile, I have no errors, I also compiled with `-Wall`, it worked. But when I run the program I get `segmentation fault, core dumped`. I can't see the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_next_prime(int nb)
{
        int i = 2;
        int notPrime = 0;

        while (i++ < 9 || notPrime != 1) {
                if (nb == i)
                        i++;
                else if (nb % i == 0)
                        notPrime = 1;
        }
        return ((notPrime) ? ft_next_prime(nb++) : nb);
}

int main()
{
        printf("%d", ft_next_prime(15));
}
```

why?

Also, can I write this?

```
while (i++ < 9 || !notPrime)
    if (nb % (i != nb) == 0)
        notPrime = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have failed to point out that:

**The problem is that you have TWO sources of infinite loop**

**1)** an infinite loop in:

```
while(i++ < 9 || notPrime != 1)
```

by having `|| notPrime != 1` you will iterate until `i++ < 9` is false and notPrime is actual 1. In another words you will be iterating until `if(nb % i == 0)` evaluates to true and variable notPrime is set to 1;

Therefore, in the call

```
return ((notPrime)? ft_next_prime(nb++) : nb);
```

it will always call recursively `ft_next_prime` again, and again. Hence, the infinite loop which ends up causing the `Segmentation fault`.

You actually meant `while(i++ < 9 && notPrime != 1)`

**2)** Furthermore, `ft_next_prime(nb++)` should be replaced by `ft_next_prime(nb+1)` otherwise you are calling the recursive function with always the same value.

---

The other problems that you have is the logic of find the prime number. A [number is prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) :

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is
> not a product of two smaller natural numbers.

You stop checking at `i++ < 9` which makes no sense because a 143 = `11 * 13` is not prime since it is divisible by 11 and 13. You need to check at least until nb / 2 (actually there is even a better lower boundary that I will leave for you to find).

---

A possible solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_next_prime(int nb){
        int notPrime = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i < nb / 2 && !notPrime; i++)
            notPrime = nb % i == 0;
        return notPrime ? ft_next_prime(nb + 1) : nb;
}

int main() {
     printf("%d", ft_next_prime(15));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I still dont understand why ```for(int i = 2; i < nb/2 || !notPrime; i++)``` wouldn't work. Because in my understanding, to go out of this loop, you need to have checked all the numbers AND the number needs to be not prime. But i am looking for a prime, therefore when the computer will find one, how will it goes out of the loop?

Comment: @Noaah Yes, so you want to continue looping when i is smaller then nb/2 (i < nb/2) and (&&) when you have not found a prime yet (!notPrime) that is why you use &&. || means continue loop if one of the following is true i < nb/2 or !notPrime;.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following line in place of your return statement:

```c
return ((notPrime)? ft_next_prime(nb+1) : nb);
```

There are a few different causes of a segmentation fault. In your case, you are running out of space on the stack.

The line `ft_next_prime(nb++)` executes and returns `ft_next_prime(nb)` — with the exact same parameter — and then increments `nb` — pointlessly but that's exactly what you told it to do.

Answer (score 1):

"Segmentation fault" means that you tried to access memory that you do not have access to.